# How to add the Recent Items stack (block)

Tags: dashboard

I just watched a youtube tutorial on how the basics of CiviCRM. The video showed a recent items list on the left of the page. My CiviCRM does not have that. Is there any way I can add it? It would be extremely helpful.

Thanks, 
Becky

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention which CMS you are using, and this is CMS-dependent feature. In Drupal, for example, you would select from the menu Structure | Blocks and then find the item labeled "CiviCRM Recent Items" and select "Sidebar First" for its region for the theme that you are using for CiviCRM (which can be different for admins, and there is a setting at bottom of /admin/appearance to set that).

Comment: hi. good stuff. i just expanded to reference fact that you need to choose which theme and to note that the civi admin side can use different theme to public facing. hope that is okay with you.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what CMS I am using. I am a brand new user and am just getting started.  I am almost positive that we are using Drupal.  I will follow your instructions and hope that it works. Thanks to both of you for your quick response. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably a theme issue. Not all themes display that block. I'd recommend Garland.